# Existence of a metric on $\Bbb Q$ which is complete and equivalent to the usual metric.

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Does there exist a metric $d$ on $\Bbb Q$ which is equivalent to the usual metric on $\Bbb Q$ such that $(\Bbb Q,d)$ is complete?

I have a confusion regarding that. Because I know that equivalence of metrics doesn't preserve completeness for arbitrary metric spaces. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know the Baire category theorem?

Comment: Yeah. Oh! Every complete metric space is of second category but Q is of first category.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "equivalent metrics"? The usage of this term is not consistent. Do you mean "metrics that induce the same topology"?

Comment: I am a foolish guy.

Comment: Yeah @bof I mean this.

Comment: There are different notions of equivalence for metrics.

Comment: Another result, not employing "Baire", is that a non-empty completely metrizable space with no isolated points has a subspace  homeomorphic to the Cantor set, which is an uncountable set

Comment: We can also show by "Baire" that a dense $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, so $\Bbb Q$, which is dense in $\Bbb R$, is not $G_{\delta}$ in $\Bbb R.$ And now quote another result: If $Y$ is a subspace of a completely metrizable space $X$ then $Y$ is completely metrizable iff $Y$ is $G_{\delta}$
 in $X$.